# Numerical estimation

Tags: number-theory, estimation

Show that the numerical value of the expression

$\frac{2\times4\times6\times\dots\times2020}{1\times3\times5\times\dots\times2019}$

is between 44 and 64.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\frac{2\cdot4\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n)}{1\cdot3\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}
=\frac{2^{2n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$$

Then use the Stirling formula ($n=1010$)
$$
n! \sim  \sqrt  {2\pi n} n^n e^{-n}
$$

Comment: Why did you invert the fraction?

Comment: @Cactus Because I had the formula for the inverted fraction at my hand - corrected (=inverted).